# Factory reset install blocked by Google FRP

Tags: frp

I have a Tecno Phantom 8. It has Android 7.
I'm trying to reinstall it using the "Recovery Mode" via "Factory Data Reset".
Google has something called FRP.
I do not have the google account that was registered in the phone. I tried to use my own google account. But FRP blocks the reinstallation of the phone without the original email.

That's good but kinda dumb since I cannot even reinstall my own phone. And now I'm stuck in the setup screen.

Any idea how I can do it ? Should I buy any tool that can help ?

Comment: FRP is a protection that was added for preventing that a phone thief (who doesn't know the phone PIN or Google password) can erase the phone data and then sell it as used phone.

Comment: @Robert lol I'm screewed. The phone is locked. I was trying to root it and now this bugs me so much.

Comment: There is a simple rule to avoid FRP: Always perform factory reset from with the main Android OS in settings or delete Google account from account list. The FRP will not trigger. There are also tools that claim to bypass FRP, not sure how reliable they are.

Comment: @Robert well I did not follow that rule and now I'm stuck.